# what does 'invalid gem format' mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does this mean I've hosed my ruby/gem/rails environment somehow? I've been using InstantRails2-0 happily for awhile now, but recently decided to upgrade rails. It has been a major pain so far. First I had issues getting the latest gem version, rubygems-update couldn't get the latest. I was finally able to get the latest gem version by manually downloading it and running setup.rb for rubygems-1.3.5.

When I do '`gem update rails`', I get the following error:

invalid gem format forr C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/activesupport-2.3.5.gem

I tried manually downloading the activesupport gem and doing 'gem install local [path to gem]'. This appeared to work, so I did the same with rails 2.3.3.gem, but then got the same invalid gem format error, but for activerecord-2.3.3.gem.

My gem version is 1.3.5. Current rails version is ....not working anymore because of RubyGem version error: activesupport(2.1.1 not = 2.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

This post might be helpful: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/137985

You might have to clear out rails and its dependencies the gem `cache` directory.  You also might try `gem uninstall` on the offending gems first

Comment: thanks for the link, I should've searched there first; I'm having to manually install each separate gem, so there must be another root issue somewhere; I've gone through activesupport, activerecord, rack, actionpack...; I tried to go back to rails 2.3.3 since I don't need the absolute latest and greatest, but am still getting the 'invalid gem format' everytime I try to install rails, just with a different gem each time